# How to make a trigger that lower input before insert in Sqlite SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, lowercase

I made a table in SQLITE like so :

```
CREATE TABLE arbres(id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, essence TEXT NOT NULL) 
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('arbres', 'geometry', 2154, 'POINT', 'XY');
```

I need to copy that line into a "log table" with the following trigger and everything works correctly.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_save_insert_arbres
AFTER INSERT ON arbres
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO logtable (id, id_arbres, essence, geometry)
    VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.id_evs, NEW.essence NEW.geometry);
END;
```

But i need to put the "essence" value into lower case before inserting the row in both table. So i tried to write a trigger that would do that :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_suppr_lower_arbres 
BEFORE INSERT ON arbres 
FOR EACH ROW    
    when id = NEW.ID
    BEGIN
    UPDATE  arbres     
    SET essence = LOWER(NEW.essence);

END;
```

that doesn't work i got this error : SQLite : no such column: id
SQL: INSERT INTO "arbres"("geometry","essence") VALUES (GeomFromWKB(?, 2154),?)

What can i do to solve my problem ? i tried a few other things but i am confused about the way to do modify something before updating.